# Opening a pdf and videos new tab in a browser instead of dowloading using third party plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-modal

I want to open a pdf or video files in a browser new tab instead of downloading them.

How should I approach the task?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code can help you

```html
<object data="http://yoursite.com/the.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="750px" height="750px">
    <embed src="http://yoursite.com/the.pdf" type="application/pdf">
        <p>This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="http://yoursite.com/the.pdf">Download PDF</a>.</p>
    </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: I am uploading pdf file to server and it will give some id. I will hit the below API to get the pdf file. sample URL: test/test1/id

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about using third party plugins but you can use the `target = "_blank"` attribute in the HTML `<a>` tag

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_target

Comment: Already I am using the same code, it's downloading the file instead of open. Is there any solution?